# Laravel 7 Eloquent: Method refresh() on a model ignores default (nested) eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm saving/updating a model and use the **refresh()** method to output the new data.

The Laravel documentation says:

> If you plan on accessing the relationship after using the save or saveMany methods, you may wish to use the refresh method to reload the model and its relationships

#### Controller

```
  public function store()
  {
    //
    $comic = new Comic;
    $comic->fill($this->validateComic());
    $comic->save();
    return $comic->refresh();
  }

  public function update(Comic $comic)
  {
    //
    $comic->fill($this->validateComic());
    $comic->save();
    return $comic->refresh();
  }
```

#### Model

In the Comic model i defined default eager loadings:

```
  protected $with = ['series', 'series.publisher'];
```

This works perfect for a simple GET method. But if i save the model and use **refresh()** on it, the output loses its relationships.

Also the behaviour is different for the store()- and the update()-methods. The **store()**-method gives me no relationship. The **update()**-method returns **only** the series relationship (but not the nested one).

Is this a bug or am i missing something in the documentation?

Thanks.

#### Example data

```
{
"comic_id":21,
"series_id":5,
"comic_issue":"2",
"comic_name":"Test after 6",
"status_id":1,
"comic_rating":null,
"comic_release_date":"2015-09-26",
"comic_read_date":null,
"comic_summary":"Summary 5",
"created_at":"2020-08-07T17:28:14.000000Z",
"updated_at":"2020-08-08T17:14:16.000000Z",
"series":
    {
    "series_id":5,
    "series_name":"Assumenda consectetur.",
    "publisher_id":4,
    "release_date":null,
    "publisher":
        {
        "publisher_id":4,
        "publisher_name":"Aliquam earum."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btw you only need `series.publisher`, it has to load `series` to load `publisher` so you don't need to specify that it loads `series` if you have `series.publisher`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually expected for how `refresh` works. `refresh` only reloads the relationships that were already loaded. In the first example there were no relationships loaded as that model wasn't retrieved from the database, it is a brand new model instance you directly created. The second example is most likely a Route Model Binding where the model has been returned from the database and because you are using the `protected $with` it was loaded with those relationships, so it has those relationships reloaded.

Comment: Ok, the first part i understand. But why is the nested relationship not loaded?

Comment: because it reloads the relationships that are loaded for "this" model ... `publisher` is on `series` which isn't the model that is being reloaded ... the current model knows nothing about anything else going on with any other model, it only knows its relationships, a nested relationship means a relationship on a different model   ...  the only thing the current model knows is there is an array named `$relations` that it stores the loaded relationships for itself ... it doesn't keep track of what any other model has loaded